# Ada types using "(<>)"

Tags: types, ada

I am looking at some legacy Ada code.

```ada
type My_Test_Type is (<>);
type My_Table_Type is array(My_Test_Type) of Integer;
```

When I try to use this code in the GNAT community IDE, I get this error:

```
ads:9:26: error: identifier expected
```

This is the line it's pointing to:

```
type My_Test_Type is (<>);
```

When I build the code in the legacy IDE, it compiles and runs fine.

Any ideas what is going on here?

I've tried this only on my local PC running GNAT Studio Community 2021 (20210423) hosted on x86_64-w64-mingw32.

The legacy system is a cross compiler for the Power PC.  It's old.

Ok, Here is more context.

I took the above lines an created a package which I am building and running in GNAT Studio community addition.

Here is the my_generic.ads

```
package My_Generic is
 generic
   type My_Test_Type is (<>);
   type My_Table_Type is array(My_Test_Type) of Integer;
   --
   My_Table : My_Table_Type;
   procedure InitMyTable(My_Table : My_Table_Type);   
end My_Generic;
```

Here is my_generic.adb

```
with GNAT.IO; use GNAT.IO;
package body My_Generic is
   procedure InitMyTable (My_Table : My_Table_Type) is
   begin
      Put_Line("Entered InitMyTable");
      for i in 1..1000 loop
         My_Table(i) := i + 1000;
      end loop;
      null;
   end InitMyTable;
end My_Generic;

Main is
--...
--...
   InitMyTable_i = new InitMyTable(My_Test_Type => range 1..10);
begin
--...
--...
   Put_Line ("Initializing My table (<>)");
   InitMyTable_i;

end Main;
```

when I build I get
error: declaration expected on the line
"InitMyTable_i = new InitMyTable(My_Test_Type => range 1..10);"

I basically have no idea what is going on here.  I've tried many different ways to get things to work.
Any of the docs I have found, including the ones suggested below, are not helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

A bit more context, please!

This compiles:

```ada
generic
   type My_Test_Type is (<>);
   type My_Table_Type is array (My_Test_Type) of Integer;
package Neil is
end Neil;
```

whereas this (using `-gnatl` for the listing) is, presumably, the error you got:

```ada
     1. package Neil is
     2.    type My_Test_Type is (<>);
                                 |
        >>> error: identifier expected

     3.    type My_Table_Type is array (My_Test_Type) of Integer;
     4. end Neil;
```

`type T is (<>)` is a **formal** discrete type definition ([ARM 12.5.2(2)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-12-5-2.html#p2)). For "discrete", see [ARM 3.2(11)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-2.html#p11).

---

Responding to the edited question,

First, please give us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your source for `main.adb` doesn’t compile, so we have to spend time guessing what you meant.

Second, using `-gnatl`,

```ada
     1. with GNAT.IO; use GNAT.IO;
     2. with My_Generic; use My_Generic;
     3. procedure Main is
     4.    InitMyTable_i = new InitMyTable(My_Test_Type => range 1..10);
           |
        >>> error: declaration expected

     5. begin
     6.
     7.    Put_Line ("Initializing My table (<>)");
     8.    InitMyTable_i;
     9.
    10. end Main;
```

fails because this isn’t the correct syntax for instantiating a generic procedure:

```ada
     1. with GNAT.IO; use GNAT.IO;
     2. with My_Generic; use My_Generic;
     3. procedure Main is
     4.    procedure InitMyTable_i
     5.      is new InitMyTable(My_Test_Type => range 1..10);
                                               |
        >>> error: missing operand

     6. begin
     7.
     8.    Put_Line ("Initializing My table (<>)");
     9.    InitMyTable_i;
    10.
    11. end Main;
```

Using the correct syntax fails because you don’t provide a matching set of generic actual parameters:

```ada
     1. with GNAT.IO; use GNAT.IO;
     2. with My_Generic; use My_Generic;
     3. procedure Main is
     4.    type Test_Type is range 1 .. 10;
     5.    procedure InitMyTable_i
           |
        >>> error: missing actual "My_Table_Type"
        >>> error: in instantiation of "InitMyTable" declared at shore.ada:7
        >>> error: instantiation abandoned

     6.      is new InitMyTable(My_Test_Type => Test_Type);
     7. begin
     8.
     9.    Put_Line ("Initializing My table (<>)");
    10.    InitMyTable_i;
           |
        >>> error: "InitMyTable_i" is undefined

    11.
    12. end Main;
```

which could be fixed something like this:

```ada
     1. with GNAT.IO; use GNAT.IO;
     2. with My_Generic; use My_Generic;
     3. procedure Main is
     4.    type Test_Type is range 1 .. 10;
     5.    type Table_Type is array (Test_Type) of Integer;
     6.    Table_Instance : Table_Type;
     7.    procedure InitMyTable_i
     8.      is new InitMyTable(My_Test_Type => Test_Type,
     9.                         My_Table_Type => Table_Type,
    10.                         My_Table => Table_Instance);
    11. begin
    12.
    13.    Put_Line ("Initializing My table (<>)");
    14.    InitMyTable_i;
           |
        >>> error: missing argument for parameter "My_Table" in call to "Initmytable_I" declared at line 7

    15.
    16. end Main;
```

and also

```ada
     1. package My_Generic is
     2.  generic
     3.    type My_Test_Type is (<>);
     4.    type My_Table_Type is array(My_Test_Type) of Integer;
     5.    --
     6.    My_Table : My_Table_Type;
     7.    procedure InitMyTable(My_Table : My_Table_Type);
                                 |
        >>> error: "My_Table" conflicts with declaration at line 6

     8. end My_Generic;
```

So, there are two things going on: you shouldn’t be declaring the formal object `My_Table` in the generic (that’s what the procedure parameter is for):

```ada
     1. package My_Generic is
     2.  generic
     3.    type My_Test_Type is (<>);
     4.    type My_Table_Type is array(My_Test_Type) of Integer;
     5.    procedure InitMyTable(My_Table : My_Table_Type);
     6. end My_Generic;
```

and

```ada
     1. with GNAT.IO; use GNAT.IO;
     2. with My_Generic; use My_Generic;
     3. procedure Main is
     4.    type Test_Type is range 1 .. 10;
     5.    type Table_Type is array (Test_Type) of Integer;
     6.    procedure InitMyTable_i
     7.      is new InitMyTable(My_Test_Type => Test_Type,
     8.                         My_Table_Type => Table_Type);
     9.    Table_Instance : Table_Type;
           |
        >>> warning: variable "Table_Instance" is read but never assigned [-gnatwv]

    10. begin
    11.
    12.    Put_Line ("Initializing My table (<>)");
    13.    InitMyTable_i (My_Table => Table_Instance);
    14.
    15. end Main;
```

but

```ada
     1. with GNAT.IO; use GNAT.IO;
     2. package body My_Generic is
     3.    procedure InitMyTable (My_Table : My_Table_Type) is
     4.    begin
     5.       Put_Line("Entered InitMyTable");
     6.       for i in 1..1000 loop
     7.          My_Table(i) := i + 1000;
                          |
        >>> error: expected type "My_Test_Type" defined at my_generic.ads:3
        >>> error: found type "Standard.Integer"

     8.       end loop;
     9.       null;
    10.    end InitMyTable;
    11. end My_Generic;
```

To fix this, you need to change line 6 to loop over `My_Table’Range` (or perhaps over `My_Table_Type`), giving

```ada
     6.       for i in My_Table'Range loop
     7.          My_Table(i) := i + 1000;
                 1              2
        >>> error: assignment to "in" mode parameter not allowed
        >>> error: expected type universal integer
        >>> error: found type "My_Test_Type" defined at my_generic.ads:3

     8.       end loop;
```

Over to you!

Comment: Ada, not an acronym, is named after the lady named Ada Lovelace who is considered the world first programmer.

Comment: I think you meant to comment on the question, rather than my answer

Comment: @Simon Wright: Certainly, I was commenting about OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from the top:

```
package My_Generic is
 -- Keyword GENERIC introduces formal parameters; it is matched with a
 -- PACKAGE, PROCEDURE, or FUNCTION keyword /not/ prefixed by WITH.
 generic
   -- The "is (<>)" formal parameter matches any discrete type.
   type My_Test_Type is (<>);
   -- The following matches an array of Integer indexed by the above type.
   type My_Table_Type is array(My_Test_Type) of Integer;
   -- The following is an object of the array-type given above.
   My_Table : My_Table_Type;
 -- then InitMyTable is the procedure which is generic.
 procedure InitMyTable(My_Table : My_Table_Type);   
end My_Generic;
```

Note that in the above `My_Generic` is not actually a generic, but merely a package containing a generic.

Continuing on:

```
Main is
   -- The following is absolutely incorrect, for multiple reasons:
   -- 1) InitMyTable_i is not properly declared, if it is to be an
   --    instantiation producing a procedure, you need to say:
   --        PROCEDURE InitMyTable_i IS NEW [...]
   -- 2) The instantiation is missing two formal-parameters:
   --        MY_TABLE_TYPE and MY_TABLE
   -- 3) The construct given for formal-parameter MY_TEST_TYPE is incorrect:
   --    you are not referencing the name of a type, but instead the keyword
   --    RANGE followed by an actual range.
   InitMyTable_i = new InitMyTable(My_Test_Type => range 1..10);
begin
--...
--...
   Put_Line ("Initializing My table (<>)");
   InitMyTable_i;
end Main;
```

To illustrate these, I'll use everyone's favorite construct: the finite state-machine. (Freehand, as the compiler on this machine is incorrectly configured.)

```
Generic
   Type State is (<>);
   Type Event is (<>);
   Start : State:= State'First;
   Error : State:= State'Last;
Package Generic_FSM is

   Type Transition_Map is Array (State, Event) of State;

   -- A private type with unknown discriminants cannot be created
   -- except by a constructing function.
   Type State_Machine(<>) is private;
   
   -- Here we process a given EVENT.
   Procedure Do(Object : in out State_Machine; Trigger : Event);

   Procedure Reset(Object : in out State_Machine);
   
   -- Here we extract the current STATE. (We're using unary minus for -X syntax.)
   Function "-"(Right: State_Machine) return State;
   
   Generic
      Map : Transition_Map;
   Function Generic_Create return State_Machine;

Private
   Type State_Machine is record
      Transitions : Transition_Map:= (others => Error);
      Current     : State:= Start;
   end record;

   -- Ada 2012 expression-function syntax, extracting the current state.
   Function "-"(Right: State_Machine) return State is
   ( Right.Current );
End Generic_FSM;

-----------
Package Body Generic_FSM is
   -- Generic_Create has MAP as a formal parameter...
   Function Generic_Create return State_Machine is
      -- Here we're using the extended-return; not actually necessary, but it
      -- does a good job documenting what's happening, especially in conjunction
      -- with the qualified aggregate. 
      Return Result : Constant State_Machine:=
       State_Machine'(
           Transitions => Map,
           Current     => Start
       );
   End Generic_Create;

   Procedure Reset(Object : in out State_Machine) is
   Begin
      Object.Current:= Start;
   End Reset;

   Procedure Do(Object : in out State_Machine; Trigger : Event) is
      This : State renames Object.Current;
   Begin
      if This /= Error then
         This:= Objet.Transitions(This, Trigger);
      end if;
   End Do;
End Generic_FSM;
---------------------------------------
Procedure Example is
  Type XState is (xs_Begin, xs_Error, xs_One, xs_Two, xs_Three);
  Type XEvent is (Go, Stop);
  
  -- Here we instantiate Generic_FSM.
  Package FSM is new Generic_FSM(
     Start => xs_Begin,
     Error => xs_Error,
     Event => XEvent,
     State => XState
    );
  Transitions : Constant Transition_Map:=
    ( Error    => (others => Error),
      xs_One   => (Go => xs_Two,   Stop => xs_Three),
      xs_Two   => (Go => xs_Three, Stop => xs_One),
      xs_Three => (Go => Error,    Stop => xs_Two),
      xs_Begin => (Go => xs_One,   Stop => Error)
    );
  Function Make is new FSM.Generic_Create(Map => Transitions);

  Actual_State_Machine : FSM.State_Machine:= Make;
Begin
  -- State-machine operations here.
End Example;
```

That should give you some insight into what you were doing wrong, and hopefully pointers on how to use generics in Ada.